# mintsources doesn't work for unknown reason

Tags: linux-mint, troubleshooting

I was rooted and accidentally run `mintsources` on my Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1919, in <module>
    Application().run()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 968, in __init__
    self.detect_official_sources()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1834, in detect_official_sources
    self.update_flags()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1841, in update_flags
    if selected_mirror[-1] == "/":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

---

I don't know if that is the reason why I can't run it as normal user now I get absolutely the same result after entering my password in GUI:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1919, in <module>
    Application().run()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 968, in __init__
    self.detect_official_sources()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1834, in detect_official_sources
    self.update_flags()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1841, in update_flags
    if selected_mirror[-1] == "/":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

---

Since I do not understand the traceback calls, I trust you will help me out with this, I did not use `mintsources` like for a year, so maybe it isn't the reason, I just don't know, where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, I removed all double spaces (and more extra spaces) from this file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

I remembered I edited it to my liking with more spaces to have columns aligned. And also to combine some entries.

Those combinations obviously don't mind, but extra spaces do (to `mintsources`, not `apt`).

---

So in the end, it looks like this:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana main upstream import backport 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

---

Afterward, I am able to run `mintsources` both as normal user, and root as well.